# How to remove "More >" from Win10 start menu context popup?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, desktop-customization

To run something as administrator from Windows 10 Start Menu you have to right click the shortcut and then click again on the "More >" option, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: win10 start menu context popup actual]

I have to use this too often (not just to run as administrator, but also to open file location etc). This multi-level context popup mechanic just does not seem to work for me.

Is it possible to move all items from this "More >" group to the main context popup, so that it looks something like below?

[image: win10 start menu context popup desired]

Answer (score 1):

"you can return to the glory days of Windows 7–and still keep much of the Windows 10 functionality–with a Start menu replacement like like **Start10** or **ClassicShell**." 
then enable cascade expanded option in context menus.
ref : howtogeeks.com

from winaero.com
[image]

my Classic start menu on Win8.1
[image]

No I dont remember Registry location. If you prefer above get **Classic Start Menu**
Another way is create folders of your favourite App links (work,players,web,security etc) and no other shortcuts on desktop (organize it) then add toolbar to taskbar> Desktop and place at top of screen for drop-down menus of Apps.

Comment: But, just to make sure, there is no native setting or policy for this?

Comment: Above property is native setup....search ... start menu property. and that is all there is.".mouse over open " so I use Classic Shell.  "more" can be disabled in registry ... but not tried , since I dumped Win X

Comment: I meant native as in without a third party app, so a registry tweak would be exactly that. Do you still remember where exactly in registry that was? Thanks

Comment: I appreciate this, thanks. However, what I'm asking for is not to organise applications in the start menu, but rather just the context right click menu. I will check whether the third party software you mentioned does this.

Comment: MS wants you think more like a smart phone (dumb)